# How to vertically center a dynamically-sized view below some text

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to center a ListView vertically on the screen. Directly above the ListView, I want to display some text (the list should be centered, not the text).

The problem is that the ListView has dynamically changing contents (e.g., number of lines). When there are few lines and the ListView fills only a portion of the screen, I want the ListView centered, with text above. When the ListView is full and would be larger than the screen, I want the text to be displayed at the top of the screen and the ListView filling up the remaining space underneath.

My current layout (below) works great when the ListView is small, but the text gets pushed off the top of the screen when the ListView becomes big.

Any suggestions for keeping the text visible when the ListView grows?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FF000000">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:text="Please select level pack..."
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_above="@id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:divider="#000000"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did u try to change from android:layout_above="@+id/list" in the TextView to android:layout_below="@+id/title" in your ListView? This should bring you the wanted effect.

Comment: Doing this, the `android:layout_centerVertical` in the ListView is ignored, and both the TextView and ListView are simply placed one after the other at the top of the screen.

Comment: You have to add android:layout_centerVertical="true" to the TextView (of course) and to the ListView, too.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work, as then the TextView will be centered on the screen, and the ListView (no matter how large) will be squished into the space underneath...

Answer (score 0):

One of the problem i can see currently is in the line

```
android:layout_above="@+id/list"
```

should ideally be

```
android:layout_above="@id/list"
```

Not sure if that is the culprit.

EDIT 1:

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="Please select level pack..."
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/title"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:divider="#000000" />
```

Comment: I'll have to read up on what the difference is, but no, this made no difference. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: +id is used for creating a new resource entry to R.java and directly id is used to refer to an existing entry which is already present.Can you try placing the listview code above the textview with the above mentioned change.

Comment: Same result I'm afraid: works fine when the list is short, but the text gets pushed off the top when the list grows longer.

Comment: Editted my answer with some sample code which works fine for me.Hope it helps.

Comment: While that does indeed prevent the text from getting cut off with a long list, it doesn't vertically center the ListView when the list is short.

Comment: For that the best you can do is to either centreVertically the textView and the ListView will follow or remove the textView alltogether and try using addHeaderView(View v) http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView(android.view.View, java.lang.Object, boolean)